# Перезаписал глобальную переменную x, но она не перезаписывается

Tags: javascript

Output: "Вася" имеет возраст "19" и он undefined

```
let name = prompt("Enter your name:",);
let age = +prompt("Enter your age:",);
var x;


function checkAge(age, x){

    if(age >= 1 && age <= 17) {
        x = "Ребенок";
    } else if(age >= 18 && age <=100) {
        x = "Не ребенок";
    }
}

alert(x); //output: undefined

function about(name, age) {
    checkAge(age, x);
    alert(`${name} имеет возраст ${age} и он ${x}`);

}

about(name, age); //Output: "Вася" имеет возраст "19" и он undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS воспринимает эту переменную как переменную из параметров функции, если хотите работать с глобальной переменной уберите её название из принимаемых параметров

```
function checkAge(age){
```

И передавать её в таком случае не надо

```
checkAge(age);
```